# Efficient Way to Retrieve Contacts with Details

Tags: android, contacts

What is the most efficient way to retrieve All Contacts with following fields
PhoneNumber,DisplayName,AccountType,ContactID,LookupID, ImageUri without having to use second cursor.

Comment: What have you tried yet. What do you think what the most efficient way. Show some code. Post your different ways of retrieving the contacts.

Comment: @SAM if he knew the most efficient way he wouldn't ask